# How can I Merge Two LINQ DataSources into a single table for a chart?

Tags: vb.net, linq, merge, datasource

I'm trying to get two ask my SQL server to calculate two different values values for each day of the month and put them into a single table to use in a graph.

I've tried to merge them into a single DataSource with Union and it fails to compile. The following code gives me the results I need in two different DataSources.

This code provides me with the results I need.

```
    Dim ChartDataOpen = (From a In db.Alarms _
             Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.IsClosed = False _
             Group a By CalendarDate = a.Generated.Value.Date Into g = Group _
             Select New With {CalendarDate, .AlarmCount = g.Count()})

    Dim ChartDataClosed = (From a In db.Alarms _
             Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.IsClosed = True _
             Group a By CalendarDate = a.Generated.Value.Date Into g = Group _
             Select New With {CalendarDate, .AlarmClosedCount = g.Count()})
```

This code is my issue, I cannot find a clever way to merge the two datasources based on their calendar date (1/16/2015) and add them into a single datasource to be used in a chart.

```
    Dim ChartData = ChartDataOpen.Union(ChartDataClosed)

    RadHtmlChartAvg.DataSource = ChartData
    RadHtmlChartAvg.DataBind()
```

Final working code:

```
    Dim ChartData = (From a In db.Alarms _
     Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
       And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
     Group a By CalendarDate = a.Generated.Value.Date Into g = Group _
     Select New With {
          CalendarDate,
          .AlarmCount = g.Count(),
          .AlarmOpenCount = g.Count(Function(a) a.IsClosed = False),
          .AlarmClosedCount = g.Count(Function(a) a.IsClosed = True)
          })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is a structure in which you see the open and closed counts in one row:

```
Dim ChartData = (From a In db.Alarms _
         Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
           And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
         Group a By CalendarDate = a.Generated.Value.Date Into g = Group _
         Select New With {
                             CalendarDate,
                            .AlarmCount = g.Count(Function(x) Not x.IsClosed)
                            .AlarmClosedCount = g.Count(Function(x) x.IsClosed)
                         })
```

You should be able to plot this in a chart with two points or bars per date.

Comment: You are correct, I'm going for that data in a single row. 

x and a are not declared in the Select New With, could you explain that part of the code to me?

Comment: Ah darn, that's my C# dialect shining through.

Comment: I was able to figure out what you were doing and got it! Thank you. Updated OP with working code.

Answer (score 1):

Create NAMED objects with identical properties:

I can do this in C#.  You'll need to convert for VB.NET

```
public class CalendarCount
{
     public dateTime CalendarDate {get; set;}
     public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

This part i'm gona guess the vb syntax:

```
Dim ChartDataOpen = (From a In db.Alarms _
         Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
         And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.IsClosed = False _
         Group a By CalendarDate = a.Generated.Value.Date Into g = Group _
         Select New CalendarCount With {CalendarDate, .Count = g.Count()})

Dim ChartDataClosed = (From a In db.Alarms _
         Where a.Generated >= FirstDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) _
         And a.Generated <= LastDayOfMonth(DateTimeNow) And a.IsClosed = True _
         Group a By CalendarDate = a.Generated.Value.Date Into g = Group _
         Select New CalendarCount With {CalendarDate, .Count = g.Count()})
```

Comment: But how do I merge the two results into a single source?